# How to customize slider-handlers with an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

does anybody know how to customize the handlers in a JQuery Range Slider? I've been searching in internet and there are variety of answers, and most of them point to change the ui-slider-handle class setting the background with the image you want to be displayed. Well, I've tried everything but it doesn't change anything. Maybe I'm missing something. I show you my code

These are the classes that I've overriden from jquery-ui. There are more in the library but these are the ones I've overriden. Notice I've set the image in ui-slider ui-slider-handle class

slider.css

```
.ui-slider-horizontal {
    height: .2em;
    top: .15em;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle {
    top: -.6em;
    margin-left: -.6em;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-range {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: .7em;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    background-color: red;
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.ui-widget-content {
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    background: grey url("images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
    color: #222222;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    position: absolute;
    background: url(../images/handle.png) no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 1.2em;
    height: 1.2em;
    cursor: default;
    -ms-touch-action: none;
    touch-action: none;
}
```

And this is my html

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#slider-range1").slider({
            animate: "fast",
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            values: [75, 300],
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                $("#amount-min1").val(ui.values[0] + "€");
                $("#amount-max1").val(ui.values[1] + "€");
            }
        });
        $("#amount-min1").val($("#slider-range1").slider("values", 0) + "€");
        $("#amount-max1").val($("#slider-range1").slider("values", 1) + "€");
    });
</script>
<div class="filter-results">
    <div class="wrapper-title-range">
        <p class="text-title-range">Rango valoración</p>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-range">
        <div id="slider-range1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="min-value">
        <input type="text" id="amount-min1" class="input-value min">
    </p>
    <p class="max-value">
        <input type="text" id="amount-max1" class="input-value max aligned-right">
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simle way to do this would be to manipulate the style with javascript when starting and stopping the slide.

```
    $(function() {
    $("#slider-range1").slider({
        animate: "fast",
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        values: [75, 300],
        create: function( event, ui ) {
          $(".ui-slider-handle").show();
          $(".ui-slider-handle").css("background",'grey url("http://www.tramsy.com/www/img/share2.png") 50% 50% repeat-x');              
        },
        slide: function(event, ui) {
          $("#amount-min1").val(ui.values[0] + "€");
          $("#amount-max1").val(ui.values[1] + "€");              
        }
    });
    $("#amount-min1").val($("#slider-range1").slider("values", 0) + "€");
    $("#amount-max1").val($("#slider-range1").slider("values", 1) + "€");
});
```

Comment: Thank you Paul Lernmark!! Very good question. But it just works when I move the handle to the right or to the left. I need to be when slider initialize. Is that possible??

Comment: Ok, I changed the example above. Use the create-event to show the image and handle when the slider is created.

Comment: Instead of changing the css attribute you could possibly toggle a class with the toggleClass function, but I did not try that.

Comment: I have the image I want displayed in the ui-slider-handle but the background is black. Do you know if there is any way the background to be transparent?? I've put it just before url("http://s2.subirimagenes.com/privadas/previo/thump_2312317handleslider.png") but nothing happens

Comment: Have you tried adding for example opacity:0.6 :
 $(".ui-slider-handle").css("opacity","0.6");